# hypothesis testing practice question

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

This is a practice question for a final exam.

Two types of cordless weed-trimmer batteries are tested. One group of 5 batteries averaged $1.4$ hours, while the other group consisting of 8 batteries, averaged $1.2$ hours.

A) What null and alternative hypotheses would you establish to determine 
   whether or not the battery life differs between the two types?

ANS: I think the answer to this is

$H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$

$H_1: \mu_1 \neq \mu_2$

B) What test statistic is appropriate if
${σ_1}^2
= 6.7$
$  
{σ_2}^2$
= 5.2.  (Please print out the appropriate 
formula.)

Ans: I think it is Z distribution. I have no idea why its just an intuition that it may be Z distribution. Could use some help or advice on how to identify the distribution.

C) Construct the appropriate critical values, assuming $α =0.05$. Would you accept the null or 
the alternative hypothesis?

Ans. Definitely need help here. Completely lost.

D) What p-value would you report if α is not specified?

Comment: You need some assumptions on the distribution in the two groups in order to say anything about which test statistic to use. The $Z$-statistic is alright to use _if_ the battery lifetime in the two groups follow a normal distribution (possibly different) _and_ there is independency between the two groups.